# How to write negative number in obj C?

Tags: objective-c, numbers

I´m trying to write a negative number like this:

```
} else if ([newsCondition.temperature floatValue] == -7.0f) {
```

but that won´t trigger it and the negative symbol is black whilst the number is blue. How can I write the number so that it triggers when temperature isEqual to -7.0 degrees?

Comment: `-7.0f` is a negative floating-point literal value in Objective-C (the syntax is fine, even if the editor highlighting looks off). However, you'll want to use an epsilon or range comparison most of the time with floating-point values: `.. if (temp <= -21f) { /* wth? */ } else  if (temp <= -7f) { /* brr!!!* / } else if (temp <= 0) { /* chilly */ } ..`

Comment: It's not so simple to check if `float` == `float`

Comment: Ah nice! Thanx user28646740

Answer (score 1):

The way you've written your negative number (`-7.0f`) is correct.

As for your code not triggering: the floating point representation of numbers is not perfect, and you have to be aware of these issues when comparing floating point numbers to each other.

If you're wanting to compare two floating point numbers, you can use an 'epsilon' (i.e. acceptable error) for the comparison. This is basically checking if the numbers are close enough.

Simple naive example:

```
#define EPSILON 0.00001f

float x = 0.09f;
float y = 0.0901f;

if (abs(y - x) < EPSILON) {
    // close enough to be considered equal;
    // do something here
}
```

For more discussion, see http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/

Answer (score 0):

> Floating-point arithmetic is considered an esoteric subject by many
>   people. This is rather surprising because floating-point is ubiquitous
>   in computer systems. Almost every language has a floating-point
>   datatype; computers from PCs to supercomputers have floating-point
>   accelerators; most compilers will be called upon to compile
>   floating-point algorithms from time to time; and virtually every
>   operating system must respond to floating-point exceptions such as
>   overflow. This paper presents a tutorial on those aspects of
>   floating-point that have a direct impact on designers of computer
>   systems. It begins with background on floating-point representation
>   and rounding error, continues with a discussion of the IEEE
>   floating-point standard, and concludes with numerous examples of how
>   computer builders can better support floating-point.

From [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)